# No such signal Scene::sceneRectChanged(QRectF) in graphicsview\qgraphicsview.cpp:1723

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, signals-slots

I was trying to use use signals and slots in one of my class when I got this message as soon as I run the application :

`QObject::connect: No such signal Scene::sceneRectChanged(QRectF) in graphicsview\qgraphicsview.cpp:1723`

My class `Scene` derives from `QGraphicsScene` and `QObject`

Why is the control checking for such a signal in the library files ?

I have actually not used this signal in any of the connections I am making. I just have a custom `SIGNAL` called `void sceneChanged();` in my derived class.

Comment: Make sure your class declaration has `Q_OBJECT` macro and re-run qmake.

Comment: Try to remove QObject inheritance, you should inherit only QGraphicsScene.

Comment: @Chernobyl Thanks! Can you post that as an answer, i will accept it.

Comment: Qt does not support multiple `QObject` inheritance. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said:

> My class Scene derives from QGraphicsScene and QObject

It is source of problem, because `QGraphicsScene` is already `QObject` subclass, so you don't need manually inherit `QObject`. Just remove this unsuitable inheritance and all will be fine.

About `graphicsview\qgraphicsview.cpp:1723`. Currently this code you can see [here](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsview.cpp#L1726).

```
if ((d->scene = scene)) {
      connect(d->scene, SIGNAL(sceneRectChanged(QRectF)),
              this, SLOT(updateSceneRect(QRectF)));
```

You don't use this signal of course, but when you set your custom scene to the view, view make all needed connection to be able to serve scene. Because of your mistake (multiple inheritance), signal (`sceneRectChanged`) was not created, so you got this error.